# Error- local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, loops

What I'm sure is another simple error, but I'm going around in circles. I'm trying to get it to show the first 10 lines in a csv using a function. I can get 1 line to show before it throws an error. Maybe my `rows=0` needs to be moved down further, but I'm not sure and my attempts at moving it hasn't worked?

```
rows = 0

def lines():
    with open('iamacsvfile.csv') as file:
        dictreader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in dictreader:
            print(row)
            rows=rows+1
            if(rows>=10):
                break

lines()
```

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [57], in <cell line: 14>()
     11             if(rows>=5):
     12                 break
---> 14 lines()

Input In [57], in lines()
      8 for row in dictreader:
      9     print(row)
---> 10     rows=rows+1
     11     if(rows>=5):
     12         break

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rows' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Put `rows = 0` inside the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to research questions before asking. For example, what happens if you try [copying and pasting the interesting part of the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=local+variable+referenced+before+assignment)?

Comment: It depends if you want *rows* to be local or global. If the former then move *rows = 0* inside the function. If the latter add *global rows* inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def lines():
    rows = 0
    with open('iamacsvfile.csv') as file:
        dictreader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in dictreader:
            print(row)
            rows=rows+1
            if(rows>=10):
                break

lines()
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying further down. I'll get there... hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Your rows is outside the function so the lines function cannot access the variable. Try moving rows inside the lines function like this.

```
def lines():
    rows = 0

    with open('iamacsvfile.csv') as file:
        dictreader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in dictreader:
            print(row)
            rows=rows+1
            if(rows>=10):
                break

lines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `rows`.

But you don't need that, since `csv.DictReader` has `line_num` property, which increases with each iteration. It's better to use:

```
for row in dictreader:
    print(row)
    if dictreader.line_num >= 10:
        break
```

Comment: That's good to know. Still learning and so many ways to do something. I'm taking the long winded route currently.